# Python3 - Pyqt5 how to end loops in threads by exception or pressing the exit button

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, loops, pyqt5

Im new to python and pyqt and have a problem I was not able to solve yet:
The following program has 3 while loops in its GUI, running from a value to zero. Ive put those loops in seperate QThreads to execute them at the same time.
Problem: if I press the exit button of the window, loops go on and still run in the console, putting out the threadcount (which is why I know they`re still running). How can I stop this by exiting the program?

Sorry for the messy code. As I said, python is new to me...

Main class:

```
class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    counter = pyqtSignal(int)
    counting = False
    #QtWidgets.QWidget

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

One of the loops put in a thread:

```
#Start des Reinigungsprozesses Becken 1
def becken1start(self):
    self.sekunden1 = value1 * 60
    if self.pushButton1.isChecked():
        if  value1 == 0:
            self.pushButton1.setChecked(False)
            self.showMessageBox('Bitte Laufzeit der Reinigung wählen')
        else:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run1)
            thread.start()
            print("Active Threads :", threading.activeCount())
    else:
        pass

#Ausführen des Threads für den Countdown Becken 1
def run1(self):
    while self.sekunden1 > -1:
        sleep(1)
        GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT) 
        GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
        self.dial1.setDisabled(True)
        self.lcdNumber1.display(self.sekunden1)
        self.pushButton1.setText("läuft")
        #QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()
        print("Active Threads :", threading.activeCount())
        self.sekunden1-=1
        if self.pushButton1.isChecked():
            continue
        else:
            break
    self.dial1.setDisabled(False)
    self.pushButton1.setText("BECKEN 1")
    self.lcdNumber1.display(value1)
    self.pushButton1.setChecked(False)
    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Exit part:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook
    def my_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
        print(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit()

    sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Application(threading.Thread)
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Start des Reinigungsprozesses Becken 1
def becken1start(self):
    self.sekunden1 = value1 * 60
    if self.pushButton1.isChecked():
        if  value1 == 0:
            self.pushButton1.setChecked(False)
            self.showMessageBox('Bitte Laufzeit der Reinigung wählen')
        else:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run1)
            thread.daemon = True 
            thread.start()
            print("Active Threads :", threading.activeCount())
    else:
        pass
```

Making the thread a daemon means the thread won't stay up if the main thread dies.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Cool!
Sadly, your approach doesn`t work...
Maybe, I should have mentioned that the function run1 and beckenstart1 are in the Main class....
Also: do I have to import anything to use the daemon?